# Android Access Fragment Variable

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

What I am basicaly trying is to access a variable inside a Fragment and get rid of it in my activity.

It worked to get the variable of the activity in my fragment but not the other way around:

what I did:

```
// get method of MainActivity
final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
```

is it even possible to make this "the other way around"?

(Access variable of Fragment in my Activity)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement listeners.
You can read more about here:[Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Here is a code example how to pass data (or `null`) from Activity to a Fragment:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements FragmentCommunicator{


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).fragmentCommunicator = this;

}
@Override
public void passDataToFragment(String str) {
    //str is the string variable you pass from the Activity, it can be null...

    }
}}
```

Next the FragmentCommunicator Class:

```
public interface FragmentCommunicator{
public void passDataToFragment(String str);}
```

And the Activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

public FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator;


public void someMethod(String someString) {

 fragmentCommunicator.passDataToFragment(someString);


}}
```

When you call `passDataToFragment()` from the Activity it will pass the string (or any other variable) to the fragment method `passDataToFragment()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your fragment by id/tag from fragment manager and do whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

that's super easy.
if you are adding your fragments in runtime (using FragmentManager)
you are creating objects of that fragment...just keep the reference with you and you are good to call any function or access any variable of the fragment.
e.g. you fragment is MyFragment

```
MyFragment mf = new MyFragment();
```

getSupportFragmentManger().beginTrans......you know the code to add a fragment
then simply call any method...for say... change() by mf.change();

or you can do something like

```
MyFragment mf = (MyFragment) findFragmentById(R.id.container);
and then again mf.change();
```